# Using up/down arrow to focus and select list values with AngularJS

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I have an `input` element and when its contents changes - a `ul` list is populated. I am able to focus on mouse over using css.

Questions:

1) How can I **focus** a `ul > li` list values using **up/down arrow key** ?
2) How to **select** a `ul > li` value using **Enter key**?

Please refer http://jsfiddle.net/3etbtfwL/458/

Comment: were you able to resolve the issue?

Comment: @StanislavKvitash Technically no. Below answer is working but after I mouse hover(focus) to drop down value, I'm unable to use up/down key to select drop down values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`ngKeydown`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngKeydown) directive on the `input` element to handle the `keydown` event and check what <kbd>key</kbd> was pressed (in your case 13, 38 ,40 codes) and [`ngClass`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass) to visually represent the currently focused list element. Here is a working example:

```js
var app = angular.module('httpApp', [])
    .controller('httpAppCtrlr', function ($scope) {

        $scope.focusedIndex = 0;

        $scope.Change = function (item) {
            $scope.items = $.grep($scope.list, function (v) {
                if (v.name === item) {
                    return v.value;
                }
            });
            $scope.focusedIndex = 0;
        };

        $scope.selected = function (value) {
            $scope.selectedValue = value;
        };

        $scope.list = [
            {
                "name": "1",
                "value": "value1"
            }, {
                "name": "1",
                "value": "value2"
            }, {
                "name": "1",
                "value": "value3"
            }, {
                "name": "2",
                "value": "value4"
            }, {
                "name": "2",
                "value": "value5"
            }
        ];

        $scope.handleKeyDown = function($event) {
            var keyCode = $event.keyCode;
            if (keyCode === 40) {
                // Down
                $event.preventDefault();
                if ($scope.focusedIndex !== $scope.items.length - 1) {
                    $scope.focusedIndex++;
                }
            }
            else if (keyCode === 38) {
                // Up
                $event.preventDefault();
                if ($scope.focusedIndex !== 0) {
                    $scope.focusedIndex--;
                }
            }
            else if (keyCode === 13 && $scope.focusedIndex >= 0) {
                // Enter
                $event.preventDefault();
                $scope.selected($scope.list[$scope.focusedIndex].value);
            }
        };

    });
```

```css
.outputLists {
    padding: 6px;
    display: block;
    cursor: pointer;
    outline: 0;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
}

.outoutList {
    display: block;
    z-index: 99;
    width: 30%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 36px;
    margin: -1px 0 0;
    border: 1px solid #eee;
    border-top: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background: #eee;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0 0 5px 5px;
}

.outputLists.focus {
    background: #428bca;
}
```

```html
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.3/angular.min.js"></script>

<div data-ng-app='httpApp' data-ng-controller='httpAppCtrlr'>

    <input type="text" ng-change="Change(item)" ng-model="item" placeholder="select"
           ng-keydown="handleKeyDown($event)"/>

    <ul class="outoutList" tabindex="0" ng-keydown="handleKeyDown($event)">
        <li ng-repeat="item in items" data-item="true" data-index="0" class="outputLists" 
            ng-click="selected(item.value)" ng-class="{'focus': focusedIndex == $index}" 
            ng-mouseover="$parent.focusedIndex = $index">
            {{item.value}}
        </li>
    </ul>
    <lable>
        Selected Value: {{selectedValue}}, Vocused index: {{focusedIndex}}
    </lable>
</div>

<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
```

**UPDATE:** To allow keyboard actions on the list element you can add `tabindex` to the `ul` and use the same `ng-keydown` event.

Comment: Technically not working. Your answer is working but after I mouse hover(focus) to drop down values, unable to use up/down key to select drop down values.

Comment: @Developer_29 See the updated answer, but the general idea here was to listen to the keyboard events, so using the same technique on the `ul` element you can achieve the desired behavior.

Comment: how to assign $scope.focusedIndex value based on Mouse over to drop down values Ex: If I mouse over to 1 drop down value, $scope.focusedIndex is not updated with value 1. Also, based on $scope.focusedIndex value in the drop down is not focus. Ex: If $scope.focusedIndex = 2 means drop down value is not focused with 2nd drop down value.

Comment: What do you mean by "$scope.focusedIndex is not updated"? It is updated with [`ngMouseover` directive](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngMouseover), I've updated the snippet so you can see how the `focusedIndex` value is changed.

Comment: Oh yes.. ngMouseover is not update MouseIndex -  ng-mouseover="$parent.focusedIndex = $index" !!! I'm using AngularJS v1.4.3.

Comment: @Developer_29 my provided example works perfect under `1.4.3`. I don't understand the issue you are facing, it could be some other kind of a problem. I gave you a general idea of how it could be solved - in your original post you haven't even tried to solve your problem. SO is not a code-writing for free service, please, make at least minimal effort to debug and the issue you have by yourself.

Comment: Thank you! You are right some problem with my code. I will check that between your code is working fine. +1